# Check if string is float, eliminate 0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app that takes latitude and longitude automatically with Google Maps geocoder. I want to write a custom validation for it to combine with other field validations. Below is my code:

```
# lib/ext/string.rb
class String
  def valid_float?
    # The double negation turns this into an actual boolean true - if you're 
    # okay with "truthy" values (like 0.0), you can remove it.
    !!Float(self) rescue false
  end
end

# config/application.rb
require 'ext/string'

# post.rb
validate :check_point

def check_point
  if !(lat || lng).valid_float?
    ...
  end
end
```

In my `Post` form, I used firebug to enter `asdf` for `:lat` field, it returned error that `valid_float?` method was not found.

I then try some debugging:

`abort(lat.to_s.valid_float?) # 0.0 true`

It seems like any characters other than numbers entered in `:lat` field would become `0.0` when I `to_s` it. But `to_s` is the only way to get the `valid_float?` working. Why is `to_s` converting all text to `0.0`?

I also did `rails c` to test:

```
"1.234234".valid_float? # true
"asdf".valid_float? # false
"0.0".valid_float? # true
```

What must I do to get it working? Thanks.

Comment: The lat and lng fields are fields of the Post model? If their types are float, Rails probably converts them when you assign the values.

Comment: Yes, their types are float. So that's the reason why every character is converted to float?

Comment: Most probably. You can either validate the form input in the controller before assigning the values; change the data types to String and provide methods to get the values as Float; or change the lat= and lng= methods to validate the input.

Comment: what is the class of lat prior to you calling .to_s on it?

Answer (score 0):

If the Post.lat and Post.long fields have a floating point type, Rails will convert them to Float when you assign the string values from the form input.
These are some of the changes you could make:
- validate the form input in the controller before assigning the values;
- change the data types to String and provide methods to get the values as Float;
- change the lat= and lng= methods to validate the input

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_point
  if !(lat || lng).valid_float?
    ...
  end
end
```

This doesn't work the way you think it does. The expression  between the parentheses is evaluated first, then `valid_float?` is called on the result. The result of `lat || lng`, in ruby, will be lat if lat is not nil, or lng if lat is nil , so you are evaluating if one of lat or lng  can be converted to a Float.

I would write this as

```
def check_point
  if !lat.valid_float? || !lng.valid_float?
    ...
  end
end
```

I think it's more intention-revealing than the logically equivalent !(a && b) form

Comment: Thanks, but the problem lies on the conversion from text to 0.0.